# Django angular database form integration

Tags: django, angularjs, postgresql, django-forms, angularjs-routing

I am currently trying a few ways of connecting a postgre sql database that I already have defined using a django `model` with a front end angular `form` that I created within the same project. (This a a django project using a little bit angular js)

So basically I have a form which accepts data from a user, and the data needs to be stored in one of the tables of the postgre sql database that I already created.

I was following [this](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/angular-model-form.html) but there are many points that are unclear to me. Is there a better way to solve this?